# How do i repeat a trigger continuously on mouseover or hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I have the following Script, which kind of works.

If i move my mouse cursor over a link in '.sample', a 'click' is being triggered.

How can i achieve, that this click is continuously triggered (kind of a loop)?

```
$jq('.sample a').mouseover(function(){
    $jq(this).trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

I tried the following, which is not working (the click is triggered only once and then it stops):

```
$jq('.sample a').mouseover(function(){
    setInterval(function() { $jq('.nav-sub-browser a').trigger('click'); }, 100);
});
```

I also tried the following solution, which i found at stackoverflow. But this one too triggers the click only once:

```
function triggerClick() {
    $jq('.nav-sub-browser a').trigger('click');
}
var interval;
$jq('.nav-sub-browser a').hover(function() {
    interval = setInterval(triggerClick(), 100);
},
function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your 3 examples are all functionally different. The first triggers a `click` on itself. The second triggers a `click` on what appears to be a different element. The last seems closer to the first, but could be triggering a `click` on several `<a>` elements. Which do you actually want?

Comment: Thank your for your comment. Actually the first one is the one i want, which actually works, i'm just not able to trigger the click continuously. I tried all the answers below, but no one worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just click?  Or is there a specific reason you're using trigger?

```
var myInterval = false;
$('.sampleA').mouseover(function(){
   myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       $('.nav-sub-browser a').click();
   }, 100);
});

$('.sampleA').mouseout(function(){
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   myInterval = false;
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates that:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/jbenson/dpC7W/

Comment: Thank you, i tried. But it's still not working, the «click» is fired only once.

Comment: See my edit, added a jsFiddle that shows the clicks happening.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your demonstration in jsfiddle showed me the right way... it's working now. As much as i understand the script, the problem was, that there was already another function on the button i put the mouseover on it. I just deactivated this function and made a another function that uses an api from the script i use to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a **function reference** to `setInterval`, so get rid of the trailing `()` after `triggerClick`:

```
function triggerClick() { 
    $jq('.nav-sub-browser a').click();
} 

var interval; 
$jq('.nav-sub-browser a').hover(function() { 
    interval = setInterval(triggerClick, 100); 
}, function() {
    clearInterval(interval); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried, but it's not working - the click is fired only once, then nothing happens.